# SHA256 Function for Compact Framework Windows mobile

Tags: c#, hash, windows-mobile, cryptography, sha256

I'm searching for a SHA256 Function for Compact Framework Windows mobile.

I just found for SHA1 but on the web is staying that is no more secure this algorithm.

I need Help :-)

Comment: SHA1 is not so badly broken to become automatically unreliable, though attacks on it have been discovered and disclosed.

Answer (score 1):

Your options include:

- [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/)
- [cfAes](http://www.mperfect.net/cfAes/)
- [openssl](https://sourceforge.net/projects/p-tools/files/OpenSSL%20for%20Windows%20CE/)